# C# - different .NET framework versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, runtime, portability

Did anybody encounter portability issues when performing `.NET` runtime upgrade *(e.g switching from 2.0 -> 3 -> 3.5 -> 4 -> 4.5)*?

I couldn't find any proof for the fact that upgrading to a higher version of the runtime wouldn't affect the behavior of my application *(I guess this should be so, but, well, there are always hidden caveats).*

Comment: You can never prove a negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always a few changes that could change the behavior of existing code, but these are in most cases rare edge cases and are kept to a minimum. You can find a list of breaking changes for recent releases of Visual Studio:

[Visual C# 2012 RC Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh678682%28v=vs.110%29)
[Visual C# 2010 Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx)
[Visual C# 2008 Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713578%28v=vs.90%29)

Answer (score 2):

Refer following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some features may be deprecated and if you are jumping more than one update, the feature could be removed all together, causing a bit of hassle.

[What's Obsolete in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502.aspx)